# Is there a perfect group which is a finite extension of the discrete Heisenberg group $H_3(\Bbb Z)$?

Tags: group-theory

We assume that $G$ is a finite extension of the [discrete Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) $H_3(\Bbb Z)$, that is,
$$
1 \rightarrow H_3(\Bbb Z) \rightarrow G \rightarrow F \rightarrow 1
$$
where $F$ is a finite group.
Is it possible that $G$ is a perfect group?

Comment: Cross-post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294574/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The main reason is that $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ has no nontrivial finite perfect subgroup (its finite subgroups have order $\le 12$).

Hence assume by contradiction that $G$ is such a group. The action on the abelianization of $H_3$ yields a homomorphism $G\to\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. Hence it has a trivial image. Hence using the commutator map, the action on the center of $H_3$ is also trivial, and hence the action on $H_3$ is by automorphisms that are trivial both on the abelianization and on the derived subgroups, and these form an abelian group. Again using that $G$ is perfect, we deduce that its action by conjugation on $H_3$ is trivial. So $H_3$ is central. Since $H_3$ is non-abelian, this is a contradiction.